# Como posso construir um resultado de tabela usando "eventReactive" em shiny

Tags: matriz, datatable, shiny, dataframe

Como posso criar um "resultado em tabela" para cada relacionamento que escolhi no selectInput "Col" e "Row"? Dinamicaly, para cada vez que pressionar o botão 'ok'.

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  h4("Give a valor between 0 to 5, to each col/row relationship"),
  hr(),
  uiOutput("colrow"),
  hr(),
  h5("Result:"),
  tableOutput("result")
))
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  cols <<- c("Select"="", "col01" = "c01", "col02" = "c02")
  rows <<- c("Select"="", "row01" = "r01", "row02" = "r02")
  values <<- c("Select"="", 1:5)

output$colrow <- renderUI({
  div(selectInput("ipt_col", label = "Col",
                  choices = c(cols),
                  selected = cols[1],
                  width = "50%"),
      selectInput("ipt_row", label = "Row",
                  choices = c(rows),
                  selected = rows[1],
                  width = "50%"),
      selectInput("ipt_vlr", label = "Value",
                  choices = c(values),
                  selected = ""),
      hr(),
      actionButton("bt_ok", "ok")
  )
})

colrow_vlr <- eventReactive(input$bt_ok, {      
  as.data.frame(matrix(input$ipt_vlr, 1,1, dimnames = list(input$ipt_row,input$ipt_col)))
})

output$result <- renderTable({
  colrow_vlr()
})
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Deixa eu ver se entendi. Você quer ir preenchendo a tabela?

**(0)** início

```
      c01    c02
r01 
r02
```

**(1)** Col='col02'; Row='row01' e Value=1 ---> `ok`

```
      c01    c02
r01            1
r02
```

**(2)** Col='col01'; Row='row02' e Value=5 ---> `ok`

```
      c01    c02
r01            1
r02     5
```

E assim por diante?

Porque o código agora só produz:

**(0)** início

```
 ...
```

**(1)** Col='col02'; Row='row01' e Value=1 ---> `ok`

```
c02
 1
```

**(2)** Col='col01'; Row='row02' e Value=5 ---> `ok`

```
c01 
  5
```

Mas se seu problema era só fazer aparecer o número da linha na tabela então use a opção `rownames=TRUE` do `renderTable()`:

```
output$result <- renderTable(colrow_vlr(),rownames = TRUE)
```

Isso resulta no seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu quero ir preenchendo a tabela, como vc observou na primeira linha do seu comentário